# Weblogic 12c config.cmd dies windows 10

Tags: weblogic12c

I am unable to start config.cmd i.e.configuration wizard. I am using windows 10. I have tried to run using cmd. It starts and dies.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but **this is what worked for me**.

If your

- `JAVA_HOME=”C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202"`
- `PATH=”C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin”`

Change them to:

- `JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_202`
- `PATH=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin`

Note that **I don't use double quotes for the values**. This is essential as they are the ones preventing config.cmd from running in my case. Double quotes are present at first due to the space in "Program Files", this is why I have to change it to PROGRA~1

PROGRA~1 refers to “Program Files” while PROGRA~2 refers to “Program Files (x86)”. Note that an answer in reddit said the opposite, but this is what worked for me.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps after installing weblogic server:
1)navigate to server directory as below and Type Config.cmd
**example: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\bin\Config.cmd**
create new domain it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I know that you have solved the problem, but I would like to leave the way I could solve it, for future people.
The first thing they have to check is the Path environment variable.
and having the correct addresses, both the database, and the Maven, must end in "\ bin", that's the solution I had to place \ bin.
I hope I helped them.